# Android OkHttp: How to get auth token then use on subsequent calls

Tags: android, okhttp, auth-token

This should be simple but I must be missing something. So there is an authorization url which I need to pass a username and password to:

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .cookieJar(new CookieJar() {
                        private final HashMap<HttpUrl, List<Cookie>> cookieStore = new HashMap<>();

                        @Override
                        public void saveFromResponse(HttpUrl url, List<Cookie> cookies) {
                            cookieStore.put(url, cookies);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(HttpUrl url) {
                            List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.get(url);
                            return cookies != null ? cookies : new ArrayList<Cookie>();
                        }
                    })
                    .build();

HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(AUTHTOKEN_URL).newBuilder();
                            urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("username", AUTHTOKEN_USERNAME);
                            urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("password", AUTHTOKEN_PASSWORD);
                            String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();

                            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                    .url(url)
                                    .build();

                            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

When I call AUTHTOKEN_URL the result is "OK" but saveFromResponse never seems to get called, so I'm thinking something is just not right because when I make the next http call to another server that depends on this auth token is does not return any data.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check service side, First api Client like POSTMAN chrome app auth-token send via headers or json Response

Comment: Yep using postman I see  its returning an auth cookie and value. So not sure why my code is not?

Comment: show me full response ?

Comment: in postman or android?

Comment: The body is html and there are 2 cookies returned BUT the cookies are returned even if I just specify url with no parameters.

Comment: Set<String> headers = response.headers().names(); from OkHttp Response then iterate and get Get Cookie Value

Comment: Connection → keep-alive
Content-Length → 623
Content-Type → text/html; charset=utf-8
Date → Wed, 30 Nov 2016 06:14:58 GMT
Etag → W/"26f-Ks8dFng74IEdCzqsur+sNg"
X-Powered-By → Express

Comment: First show the Response via image that time only i can explain get Token from header

Comment: Expand headers value

Comment: headers don't have any token show response body ...... we can continue via chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129402/discussion-between-mike6679-and-rajesh-rajendiran).